# VSCode doesn't syntax highlight all .env files

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, syntax-highlighting, .env

VSCode being strange about environment files. Even though it shows the correct file icon for the `example.env` as a dotenv file in the file view/tab, only `.env` is syntax-highlighted correctly when opening the file.

`.env` (correct):

[image]

`example.env` (no syntax highlighting):

[image]

What's the best way to get all `.env` files syntax highlighted properly in VSCode?

Comment: what does the languageID tell you in the status bar, what if you use the `files.associations` setting

Comment: on my VSC `example.env` is a `Plain Text` file, file icons are defined in a different way compared to the languageID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code has a way to manually define the file association of certain extension types.

To do so for `.env` files:

1. Open Settings (`Ctrl` + `,` or File > Preferences > Settings.
2. Search for `file asssociation`.
3. You should see `Files: Associations`.
4. In the table under this setting, click on Add Item.
5. Under **Item**, add `*.env` and under **Value**, add `properties`.
6. Click on OK once you're done.

You can also do the same for `.env.example` files.

Switching back to your file, you should see the syntax highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just installing the "VSCode Great Icons" package. But tested your method and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess vscode env formetter extension is build to get highlights all files starting with ".env" not anything before the name in your case "example.env". I guess it is treating a separate language file which definations is not installed.
If you want to have separate env for local and production you can name them as ".env.local" for local and ".env" for production. Vscode will hightlights syntax for these.

Comment: Renaming to `.env.example` does indeed syntax highlight correctly, but then it changes the file icon to a green dollar sign. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I use the extension [DotENV](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikestead.dotenv). Works flawlessly for me.